# I need the output of an XSL file(output is XML file) which takes an XML file as input, in a folder structure

Tags: xml, xslt, output, directory

I have one XML file as input and one XSL file which transforms the input XML file to another XML file.
I need to place that output XML file in specific folder and with specific name.
How do I do that? I tried using result-document but no luck the file name is just getting displayed in the output file.

here is my XML code(Trial.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="trail_xslt.xsl"?> 
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Settings>
    <Setting Id="66" Revision="2" Type="e-mail settings"
        Name="E-mail setting" Default_Item="false">
        <SettingAttributes>
            <SettingAttribute Name="email push" Value="Yes" />
            <SettingAttribute Name="cost warning" Value="No" />
            <SettingAttribute Name="email account name style"
                Value="NONE" />
            <SettingAttribute
                Name="linkedin integration in e-mail" Value="No" />
            <SettingAttribute
                Name="show truncation limit in bytes" Value="Yes" />
        </SettingAttributes>
    </Setting>
</Settings>
```

Here is my XSL Code(Trial.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <!-- Our goal is to come up with output XML in a folder structure -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <resources>
                    <integer name="email_account_name_style">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'email account name style']/@Value = 'NONE'">
                                0
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'email account name style']/@Value = 'EMAIL'">
                                1
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'email account name style']/@Value = 'DOMAIN'">
                                2
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </integer>

                    <integer name="push_email">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'email push']/@Value = 'Yes'">
                                1
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'email push']/@Value = 'No'">
                                0
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </integer>

                    <bool name="enable_cost_warning">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'cost warning']/@Value = 'Yes' ">
                                true
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'cost warning']/@Value = 'No' ">
                                false
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </bool>

                    <bool name="enable_linked_in_connection">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'linkedin integration in e-mail']/@Value = 'Yes'">
                                true
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'linkedin integration in e-mail']/@Value = 'No'">
                                false
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </bool>

                    <bool name="truncation_size_in_bytes">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'show truncation limit in bytes']/@Value = 'Yes'">
                                true
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when
                                test="Settings/Setting[@Type = 'e-mail settings']/SettingAttributes/SettingAttribute[@Name = 'show truncation limit in bytes']/@Value = 'No'">
                                false
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </bool>
                    </resources>
                    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output XML file is this(Trial.out.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <integer name="email_account_name_style">0</integer>
   <integer name="push_email">1</integer>
   <bool name="enable_cost_warning">false</bool>
   <bool name="enable_linked_in_connection">false</bool>
   <bool name="truncation_size_in_bytes">true</bool>
</resources>
```

The above output is getting generated as Trial.out.xml 
But I need this output as con.xml in the following folder structure E:\sour\resource\values

I tried using the below chunk of code in XSL But it does not yield anything:

```
<xsl:variable name="filename"
        select="concat('E:\sour\resource\values\','con','.xml')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
    <xsl:result-document href="E:\sour\resource\values\" format="xml">
```

Kindly help me

Regards,
Lahari P

Comment: So which XSLT processor exactly do you use, how do you use it (show us your command line options or the code you use to run the XSLT processor)? All the details of what your XML looks like and which exact transformation are not really relevant if the question is simply to use a certain processor to write to a certain location. In general the `xsl:result-document` in XSLT 2/3 takes a URI so `<xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/sour/resources/values/con.xml">...</xsl:result-document>` should be the right syntax.

Comment: I added Orangevolt XSLT plugin to my Eclipse and the configured the Saxon-B 8.9  Transformer . Screenshot attached for reference.

Comment: I am unable to attach screenshot.
I added Orangevolt XSLT plugin to my Eclipse and the configured the Saxon-B 8.9  Transformer via Windows-->Preferences-->Under orangevolt XSLT-->Transformer-->changed the default Transformer configuration to Saxon-B 8.9 .If I am wrong Kindly let me the know the correct way to proceed so that I get the output file as desired.

Comment: And Is this what you suggested ?
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="filename"
    select="concat('E:/sour/resources/values/con.xml','.xml')" />
 <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />  <!-- Creating  -->
 <xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/sour/resources/values/con.xml""> 
   <resources>
--------
</xsl:result-document>

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Eclipse and how it uses Saxon to output the result of an XSLT transformation and whether it has any configuration option to simply set up folder and file name of the primary result so I can't suggest any way specific to your particular tool configuration. Note also that Saxon 8.9 is more than 10 years old, the current version is 9.8.

However, in XSLT 2.0 you can certainly use `xsl:result-document` directly inside `xsl:template match="/"` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/sour/resources/values/con.xml">
     <!-- now output results you want here with literal result elements and/or by using templates e.g. -->
     <resources>
       ...
     </resources>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

to ensure the primary result is written to a certain location. If needed or wanted you can of course use parameters or variables for more flexibility e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="file-name" select="'con.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="folder-url" select="'file:///E:/sour/resources/values/'"/>
```

at the top-level and then instead of `<xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/sour/resources/values/con.xml">` you could use `<xsl:result-document href="{$folder-url}{$file-name}">`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the needful using ant ? if yes how can I proceed?